# Permission denied in apr_global_mutex_lock

Tags: apache-2.4, tomcat, httpd

I installed apache tomcat connector and configured all the settings successfully, httpd service also started, but while loading webpage , it is throwing 500 internal service error. In error log it is showing below error:

```
Permission denied: apr_global_mutex_lock(jk_log_lock) failed
Permission denied: apr_global_mutex_unlock(jk_log_lock) failed
Permission denied: apr_global_mutex_lock(jk_log_lock) failed
Permission denied: apr_global_mutex_unlock(jk_log_lock) failed
```

Installed apache connector version : **1.2.42**

Installed httpd version : **2.4.28**

Here is my httpd.conf file

LoadModule    jk_module  modules/mod_jk.so

```
JkWorkersFile  /usr/local/apache/conf/workers.properties

JkLogFile     logs/mod_jk.log
JkLogLevel    emerg
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "
JkOptions     +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat -ForwardDirectories
JkRequestLogFormat     "%w %V %T %p %q %r %v %U"
```

I changed log level to info also, but still it isn't working.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a permission problem like the error says? Eg. that the file or directory permissions where the jg_log_lock resides is chowned to the user that is used to run httpd?

Comment: All the process was running though root only. So I don't think so there will be permission problem in folder access, Some thing to do with configurations I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution after googling. Need to uninstall **apache_ruid2** module in httpd server. The above module overrides permission. So once disable/uninstall the  module, error got rectified.